# Update vsts-npm-auth with new username and password

Tags: node.js, authentication, npm, azure-devops-rest-api

I have installed the **vsts-npm-auth** package using following command:

```
npm install -g vsts-npm-auth --registry https://registry.npmjs.com
```

And I ran **vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc** command to set the credential but I am facing below error:

[image]

Now I need to update the credential but it always fetches the existing credential. Is there any way to send **PUT** request and update the credential ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I made it work with help of my colleague.

1. Uninstall **vsts-npm-auth** package
2. remove **NPM cache**
3. delete **.npmrc** file under Users folder
4. And re-run the below command with auth flag set to false. It will ask for the creds.

   npm install -g vsts-npm-auth --registry https://registry.npmjs.com --always-auth false

Comment: Since you solved the problem by yourself, you can mark it as answer. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Comment: For anyone who's wondering how to clear NPM cache:  npm cache clean --force

Comment: Thank you.  Just running:

npm install -g vsts-npm-auth --registry https://registry.npmjs.com --always-auth false

without anything else... solved the problem for me.  After that, 
npx vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc
ran successfully and popped up the prompt for Azure creds.

Answer (score 6):

Just run "vsts-npm-auth **-F** -config .npmrc"

Answer (score 3):

If the above solution is not working. I am adding a few more steps to the above answer

1. Uninstall vsts-npm-auth package
2. remove NPM cache
3. delete .npmrc file under Users folder
   //new steps
4. https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6733#issuecomment-376604435
   As mentioned in the link remove the already existing token and details to show the login prompt again
   open regedit (windowsKey + R + type "regedit")
   delete -> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio\VssApp`
5. Restart your system
6. And re-run the below command with auth flag set to false. It will ask for the creds.

`npm install -g vsts-npm-auth --registry https://registry.npmjs.com --always-auth false`

7. `vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc`

Comment: It works for me, removing tokens in regedit is necessary

Answer (score 0):

1. Optional: Make a backup of your .npmrc file.
2. Edit the .npmrc file.
3. Delete the lines with the cached credentials. More specifically delete:

- Any line ending with `username=VssSessionToken`
- Any line starting with the comment `; This is an unencrypted authentication token.`
- Any line containing `password=`
- Any line containing `email=`

4. Save the file.
5. Run `vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc`

Answer (score 0):

The VSTS will save creds in the Windows registry. You need to remove the token to get the login prompt again.

Here is the path in Windows Registry :

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio\VssApp

[image]