# NPM packages management using VSTS

Tags: authentication, npm, azure-artifacts

I'm having trouble publishing npm packages using using Package Management feeds.

```
>vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc


vsts-npm-auth v0.25.0.0
----------------------
Creating npmrcFile. Path: H:\.npmrc
Getting new credentials for source:https://########.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/########/npm/registry/, scope:vso.packaging_write vso.drop_write


>npm publish
...

npm ERR! need auth auth required for publishing
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there a prompt window to let you to authentication when run vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc command? My steps: 1. Click Connect to Feed >npm 2. Copy registry=xxx always-auth=true to .npmrc file 3. Run npm install -g vsts-npm-auth --registry https..... 4. Run vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc

Comment: the first time I run that command an authentication window appeared. And I've logged in without errors. I followed all these steps (from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/npm/npmrc and here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3ugg3p7gTo)

Comment: Refer to this thread to remove related info and try again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43840562/update-vsts-npm-auth-with-new-username-and-password

Comment: Already followed it without solving. There is one difference if I execute the vsts-npm-auth in an admin console:
vsts-npm-auth v0.25.0.0
-----------------------
Creating npmrcFile. Path: H:\.npmrc
Could not find a part of the path 'H:\.npmrc'.

Comment: Create/copy .npmrc file to H drive and add registry=XXX always-auth=true to that file, then run vsts-npm-auth command.

Comment: There is already a .npmrc file in H: (network drive), but the drive seems not accessible from the command line (C:\>h: The system cannot find the drive specified.) if run it as administrator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145178/discussion-between-redeyes-and-starain-msft).

Comment: @ReDEyeS  I am facing the exact same issue with network drive, where when I try to run vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc, says "could not find part of the path Y:", removed the network drive, but still  its pointing to network drive only.How can I change the command to read from C: instead of Y?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .npmrc file (with the "_authToken"), was generated by the ***vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc*** in the ***H:*** drive.

I manually moved it to the user folder in order to make the ***npm publish*** working.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is moving the .npmrc file to the user folder.